# Что значит инкапсулировать?

Tags: ооп

Начал читать книгу о паттернах. В ней постоянно встречаются предложения типа

> инкапсулируйте то, что изменяется

Что значит инкапсулировать ? Слово `инкапсуляция` я понимаю как сокрытие данных о реализации некоторых участков кода для повышения уровня абстракции. Но что означает инкапсулировать до конца не ясно... В голову приходит мысль о том, что это процесс сокрытия данных о реализации. Но мое представление не всегда совпадает с контекстом из книги...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В разработке ПО есть два схожих понятия – инкапсуляция и сокрытия информации. Кто-то считает, что это синонимы, кто-то нет, но это не так и важно.

Немного истории: Дэвид Парнас в году эдак 70-м в статье “On the Criteria To Be Used in Decomposing Systems into Modules” впервые ввел понятие сокрытия информации, как ключевого инструмента проектирования. Звучал этот принцип примерно так: декомпозиция системы на модули не должна основываться на анализе блок схем или потоков исполнения. Вместо этого, каждый модуль должен прятать внутри некоторое решение (design decision), предоставляя минимальное количество информации о нем своим клиентам.

Вот небольшой пример.

Допустим, вы разрабатываете ынтырпрайз приложение, которое делает что-то важное. Любое нормальное приложение обычно требует некоторой конфигурации: ну, параметры подключения к БД или серверу, и другую ценную информацию. И вот, матерый артихектор (*) вместе с не менее матерым клиентом просят прочитать конфигурацию из конфигурационного файла.

(*) это не опечатка, пожалуйста, не правьте это!

В процессе разговора с ними вы понимаете, что никто толком не знает, почему читать конфигурацию нужно именно из файла, какой должен быть у него формат и что именно там должно храниться.

Теперь вы становитесь перед выбором: вы можете «размазать» сведения о конфигурации ровным слоем по всему приложению. Каждый компонент, которому нужны некоторые параметры, сам полезет в app config, вытянет оттуда нужные данные, пропарсит xml или json и будет готов служить. С другой стороны, очевидно, что решение о том, где именно хранится конфигурация и в каком формате, может измениться в будущем. Поэтому более вменяемым решением будет скрыть информацию о местоположении и формате конфигурации в одном модуле, например, с помощью классов `Configuration` и `ConfigurationProvider`. В этом случае, когда (да, именно, «когда», а не «если») требования изменятся, то поменяется лишь реализация класса `ConfigurationProvider`, а все остальные пользователи этого класса или конфигурации останутся неизменными. Аналогично, при изменении формата, поменяется тоже только процесс парсинга, а не потребители конфигурации.

Этот пример кажется надуманным, но это не так! Мы довольно часто сталкиваемся с изменчивостью требований, но используем, к сожалению, один из двух подходов:

•   Полностью игнорируем возможность изменения требований и делаем все в лоб или

•   Создаем супер сложное решение с десятком уровней косвенности, которое должно выдержать изменения требований в любом направлении без изменения кода вообще.

Более же разумный подход находится где-то по середине. Каждый раз, когда я начинаю разработку некоторой фичи, я думаю, сколько кусков в коде придется поменять, если требования или детали реализации существенно изменятся. При этом я не стараюсь свести количество изменений к 1 (ну, типа, если мы следуем SRP, то должно быть только одно место, в случае изменения требованй). Я стараюсь, чтобы этих мест было мало, а изменения были простыми.

Собственно, это и есть суть information hiding и его младшей сестры – инкапсуляции.

Answer (score 5):

Это значит что вы снижаете связанность с остальным кодом, и изменяя работу окружающего кода, инкапсулированная область остаётся в рабочем состоянии.

Вынося код в отдельный класс - вы его инкапсулируете.
Вынося код в отдельный метод или функцию - вы его тоже инкапсулируете.

Вся реализация прячется за интерфейсы и работает через них, превращаясь для сторонних людей в "чёрный ящик", который они не могут ковырять(если язык позволяет), либо могут ковырять, но понимают, что делают это на свой страх и риск.

Answer (score 4):

*Инкапсулировать* - значит скрывать. **Идея инкапсуляции состоит в том**, что вы скрываете реализацию ваших классов от пользователей(и программистов), предоставляя им для работы интерфейсы ваших классов. Также это подразумевает скрытие данных при помощи идентификаторов доступа(public, private, protected). Например вы программист, и вам дают доступ к библиотеке. А именно, вы подключаете некий заголовочный файл, с доступом к интерфейсам некоторых классов, и манипулируете с объектами этого класса, через методы этого класса. Это исключает возможность повреждения рабочего кода. Как то так...

Answer (score 4):

Есть метод `делатьСэндвич();`.

Реализация может быть очень изменчива:

```
добытьХлеб
    ржаной белый хлебРакфор
    прожарить?
    мякиш корочка
    ...
```

Это только добыча основы. Неполная версия.
Поэтому скрыть (инкапсулировать, как говорит нынче молодёжь) это стоит как минимум по двум причинам:

1. Не пугать конечного пользователя интерфейсом таким разнообразием, ибо пугающе это и ему знать не нужно (простота - залог используемости).
2. Чтобы случайно и/или намеренно не повредить логику работы сэндвичного завода.